# invalid hook call when using material ui appbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

In order to build a simple app bar I copied from material ui site the following component's code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import NotificationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notifications';
import MoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
 grow: {
   flexGrow: 1,
 },
 menuButton: {
   marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
 },
 title: {
   display: 'none',
   [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
     display: 'block',
   },
 },
 search: {
   position: 'relative',
   borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
   backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
   '&:hover': {
     backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
   },
   marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
   marginLeft: 0,
   width: '100%',
   [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
     marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
     width: 'auto',
   },
 },
 searchIcon: {
   padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
   height: '100%',
   position: 'absolute',
   pointerEvents: 'none',
   display: 'flex',
   alignItems: 'center',
   justifyContent: 'center',
 },
 inputRoot: {
   color: 'inherit',
 },
 inputInput: {
   padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
   // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
   paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)}px)`,
   transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
   width: '100%',
   [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
     width: '20ch',
   },
 },
 sectionDesktop: {
   display: 'none',
   [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
     display: 'flex',
   },
 },
 sectionMobile: {
   display: 'flex',
   [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
     display: 'none',
   },
 },
}));

export default function PrimarySearchAppBar() {
 const classes = useStyles();
 const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
 const [mobileMoreAnchorEl, setMobileMoreAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

 const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
 const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl);

 const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event) => {
   setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
 };

 const handleMobileMenuClose = () => {
   setMobileMoreAnchorEl(null);
 };

 const handleMenuClose = () => {
   setAnchorEl(null);
   handleMobileMenuClose();
 };

 const handleMobileMenuOpen = (event) => {
   setMobileMoreAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
 };

 const menuId = 'primary-search-account-menu';
 const renderMenu = (
   <Menu
     anchorEl={anchorEl}
     anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
     id={menuId}
     keepMounted
     transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
     open={isMenuOpen}
     onClose={handleMenuClose}
   >
     <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
     <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
   </Menu>
 );

 const mobileMenuId = 'primary-search-account-menu-mobile';
 const renderMobileMenu = (
   <Menu
     anchorEl={mobileMoreAnchorEl}
     anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
     id={mobileMenuId}
     keepMounted
     transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
     open={isMobileMenuOpen}
     onClose={handleMobileMenuClose}
   >
     <MenuItem>
       <IconButton aria-label="show 4 new mails" color="inherit">
         <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
           <MailIcon />
         </Badge>
       </IconButton>
       <p>Messages</p>
     </MenuItem>
     <MenuItem>
       <IconButton aria-label="show 11 new notifications" color="inherit">
         <Badge badgeContent={11} color="secondary">
           <NotificationsIcon />
         </Badge>
       </IconButton>
       <p>Notifications</p>
     </MenuItem>
     <MenuItem onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}>
       <IconButton
         aria-label="account of current user"
         aria-controls="primary-search-account-menu"
         aria-haspopup="true"
         color="inherit"
       >
         <AccountCircle />
       </IconButton>
       <p>Profile</p>
     </MenuItem>
   </Menu>
 );

 return (
   <div className={classes.grow}>
     <AppBar position="static">
       <Toolbar>
         <IconButton
           edge="start"
           className={classes.menuButton}
           color="inherit"
           aria-label="open drawer"
         >
           <MenuIcon />
         </IconButton>
         <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" noWrap>
           Material-UI
         </Typography>
         <div className={classes.search}>
           <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
             <SearchIcon />
           </div>
           <InputBase
             placeholder="Search…"
             classes={{
               root: classes.inputRoot,
               input: classes.inputInput,
             }}
             inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
           />
         </div>
         <div className={classes.grow} />
         <div className={classes.sectionDesktop}>
           <IconButton aria-label="show 4 new mails" color="inherit">
             <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
               <MailIcon />
             </Badge>
           </IconButton>
           <IconButton aria-label="show 17 new notifications" color="inherit">
             <Badge badgeContent={17} color="secondary">
               <NotificationsIcon />
             </Badge>
           </IconButton>
           <IconButton
             edge="end"
             aria-label="account of current user"
             aria-controls={menuId}
             aria-haspopup="true"
             onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}
             color="inherit"
           >
             <AccountCircle />
           </IconButton>
         </div>
         <div className={classes.sectionMobile}>
           <IconButton
             aria-label="show more"
             aria-controls={mobileMenuId}
             aria-haspopup="true"
             onClick={handleMobileMenuOpen}
             color="inherit"
           >
             <MoreIcon />
           </IconButton>
         </div>
       </Toolbar>
     </AppBar>
     {renderMobileMenu}
     {renderMenu}
   </div>
 );
}
```

the link is: https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#app-bar
and I got the following error when i tried to load the page(i simply used their code only and didnt add code I worte yet):

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

I think the error has something to do with the material ui icons(which heppened to me before)does anyone know why does it heppen?and how can i fix it?
I tried to search for similiar problems but nothing worked for me

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "final_project2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "mdbreact": "^5.0.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-grid-carousel": "^1.0.1",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.6.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.3",
    "ua-parser-js": "^0.7.27",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

my app.js file:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
// import Sign from './pages/Sign'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignIn from './pages/SignIn';
import MaterialUiForm from './pages/MaterialUiForm';
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import AppBar from './components/AppBar';
import PrimarySearchAppBar from './components/AppBar';


const App = () => (
  <div>
    {/* <PrimarySearchAppBar/> */}
    <AppBar/>


  </div>

);

export default App;
```

I tried using appBar and PrimarySearchAppBar and none of them worked

Comment: what is your `React` version in package.json?

Comment: How do you import this PrimarySearchAppBar component? please show your import line

Comment: import AppBar from './components/AppBar';
import PrimarySearchAppBar from './components/AppBar';

Comment: my react version is 17.0.2

Comment: @Noname, please add your `package.json` file to the question. Also I want to see how you use the `PrimarySearchAppBar` component in your parent.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: @Noname can you provide the stacktrace. I don't think it's because of `PrimarySearchAppBar`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to uninstall and re-install the library